# Adobe Premiere Pro 13.1.4 on Mojave, MacBook Pro 9.1

Tags: high-sierra, mojave, video, adobe

I recently upgraded my MacBook Pro mid 2012 (9.1) to Mojave. It has the 512mb NVIDA GT650 graphics card. When I'm using Premiere it gives me this error message.

```
    NVIDIA CUDA is not currently supported in macOS 10.14 or later.  If you are using an Apple-authorized NVIDIA GPU, you should be able to continue to use the Metal Mercury Playback Engine.
    URL: https://helpx.adobe.com/en/premiere-pro/kb/gpu-and-gpu-driver-requirements-for-premiere-pro.html

Video    NVIDIA Resman Kernel Extension v.12.0.0.0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.  NVIDIA CUDA is not currently supported in macOS 10.14 or later.  If you are using an Apple-authorized NVIDIA GPU, you should be able to continue to use the Metal Mercury Playback Engine.
    URL: https://helpx.adobe.com/en/premiere-pro/kb/gpu-and-gpu-driver-requirements-for-premiere-pro.html

Video    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri v.12.1.0.0
```

From what I understand my model is the last model that got Mojave. I would really like to push buying a new computer to the future as much as possible as it does everything I need.

Are there any solution to this? Should I just ignore it? Or would a downgrade to High Sierra be better?

Update:

I did a reinstall to High Sierra (from Mojave) and got the nvidia web drivers installed. Some of the adobe programs works on my old GPU but premiere doesnt (it requires 2gb memory). See: https://theblog.adobe.com/important-information-on-gpu-acceleration-with-cuda-and-apple-metal/

I still think my computer works better on High Sierra so the reinstall was worth it anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NVIDIA GPUs on macOS**

This information only applies if you have an older iMac (2013 or older), an older MacBook Pro (2014 or older) or an older Mac Pro with an after-market NVIDIA GPU. Modern Apple computers use AMD GPUs and no separate driver updates are required.

**For running CUDA with NVIDIA graphics:**

1. You need to be running macOS 10.13.6 (most recent version of High Sierra).
2. mac0S 10.14 (Mojave) does not currently support CUDA
3. A current NVIDIA GPU with a minimum of 2 GB of memory
4. NVIDIA display driver version 387.10.10.10.40.105.

In this case if you don't want to buy new hardware, downgrading to High Sierra would be a better option.

Sad but True.

Comment: Thank you soo much. It's such an environmental waste to throw away good working computers. I'll do the downgrade and be done with that.